# how to create 2 different Tokens Within One Contract while still being within ERC20 Standards?

Tags: solidity, smart-contract-wallets

Is it possible to create 2 different Tokens Within One Contract while still being within ERC20 Standards that can interact with each other?

Answer (score 0):

No. How would another contract just calling `transfer()` without knowing the contract is 2 different tokens behave?

Comment: is it possible to specifically state the token by it's id

Comment: As i said, how would another contract behave? Uniswap isnt aware of your ID mechanism, it wouldnt use it